# Acer One 10 Wireless Adapter Missing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, tablet

Good Afternoon everyone,

I've got a friends Acer One 10 S1002 tablet(with detacheable keyboard) and she's having issues with her wireless. It stopped working shortly after the upgrade to windows 10. According to Acer support, it should handle windows 10 100%.

Here's where it gets wierd.
If i try to change adapter settings, i cant see anything listed for network adapters, but if i go to device manager, i can see the adapter, and it appears to have no issues. It has the latest driver installed, and rolling back is not an option. I've tried disabling/enabling the adapter, but nothing changes.

I haven't fully tested it, but the bluetooth appears to be fully functional.

Googling a similar issue it seems that people with this issue have remedied it by forcing a shutdown, which did not help me at all. I've also got the latest BIOS installed.

In case anyone suggests it, there is not way to get a wired connection to this thing from adapters that i have.

Comment: I've also attempted to uninstall/reinstall the drivers to no avail.

Comment: Go here in the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network` then delete `Config` and restart the computer and see if the adapter shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first to set Show all hide devices to see if we can see this adapter in device manager.

Please see if your network adapter can be see under this registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI

The sub key name can be different with  my screenshot, please search network under this key:
[image]

If not, that could be the issue of missing device recorder, let's try to manually import from another PC with this registry key and then reinstall the adapter driver to see the results.

We can also try following commands to do the repair for system components:

Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth

SFC /scannow